# if statement inside a for loop?

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

I have a sql background and I'm learning c#.  Right now I have a for loop that operates on columns x.ph.company, x.ph.product, x.ph.productID, etc (all tab-delimited)

I want to run an if statement on x.product with something to the effect of "If x.product contains "Unspecified Product", then return "Unspecified Tech".  This is what I've got so far but I can't quite get it right.  Any help appreciated!

```
String OutputCustomer;
foreach (var x in rs_product_hit)
{
OutputCustomer = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\r\n"
, x.ph.hit_id
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.url)
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.company)
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.City)
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.State)
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.iso)
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.vendor)
, SetAsSpace(x.ph.product)
if ( x.ph.product == "Unspecified Product" )
{
   x.ph.product = "Unspecified Tech"
}
```

Comment: move it out to a local variable.

Comment: Have you looked at the .Contains() function in c#? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you give all your code please?

Comment: What do you want to return if x.product *doesn't* contain "Unspecified Product"? For either case, do you still want to return the tab delimited string?

Comment: Note that the fact that it's within a `for` loop is irrelevant.  It's the fact that it;s within another _statement_ (`String.Format`) that prevents you from using `if`.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with the Ternary syntax? There are many other ways but this seems closest to what you're already doing, to me.

```
    String OutputCustomer;
    foreach (var x in rs_product_hit)
    {
       OutputCustomer = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\r\n"
                                    , x.ph.hit_id
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.url)
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.company)
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.City)
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.State)
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.iso)
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.vendor)
                                    , SetAsSpace(x.ph.product)
                                    ,x.ph.product == "Unspecified Product" ?
                                     "Unspecified Tech" : x.ph.product);
    }
```